# 200 Response but no JSON Data returned - Restangular issue?

Tags: json, response, restangular

Using restangular and the stub hub api. I can hit this API on the firefox restclient and get a response body back with all the JSON data.

But in my app, I get a 200 but no response body... the content length even says something's there

albeit the api says you just need GET/URI endpoint and Authorization: Bearer {token}

[image: screen shot 2014-11-07 at 11 01 40 am]

[image: screen shot 2014-11-07 at 11 01 59 am]

Here's my restangular config

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myapp')
.config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider){
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://api.stubhub.com/');
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer 198u2190832190831432742(notreallymytoken)'
    });
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({
        withCredentials: false
    });
}]);
```

and here's my controller

```
$scope.searchEvents = function(){
    Restangular.one('search/catalog/events/v2?title="san francisco"').get().then(function(response){
        $scope.searchResponse = response;
    }, function(response){
        console.log("something went wrong");
    })
}
```

How can I begin to debug? I want to keep using restangular so hopefully I can get around this somehow.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem was and could be in your case too.
The Content-Type for your response would have probably been something like `application/javascript` and NOT `application/json.`
Which is why it is not caught by Restangular but by browser or REST clients.

Comment: hey so if I understand this correctly, stubhub api response is application/javascript instead of json? you can see that it is application/json in the response headers. I'm not understanding.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem, only in my case the server responded with application/javascript.