# Angular JS - $http not sending headers

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers

As the title suggest, I need to pass an authorization token but when I check the network console, I'm getting a 403 because the accept and authorization isn't there. NOTE: I removed my authorization token for this example

```
$http({
        url: 'http://api.stubhub.com/search/catalog/events/v2?title="san"',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: '',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": 'Bearer {token}'
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        $scope.searchResponse = response;
    }).error(function(error){
        $scope.error = error;
    });
```

This seems like correct syntax? What's wrong here?

EDIT: added the XHR screenshot

[image]

EDIT: 2. Here's my network traffic, HAR via paste bin:

http://pastebin.com/fiFngZSy

Comment: This syntax is perfectly OK,
Debug time, could you print screen the XHR section after request is made? on request tab please. make sure the token is there, and you can see the field.

Comment: I made this plunk using the same syntax , look in console log it's working. http://plnkr.co/edit/fWaAtpF48nHO5gGlgvN7?p=preview

Comment: Interestingly the authentication token isn't there... which is why I'm getting a 403.

Comment: would be great if you could provide more detail on the network traffic (using chrome you can save the network traffic in the network view by right clicking "Save as HAR with Content")

Comment: Did you find the anwser @Garuuk ?

Comment: @JulioMarins Unfortunately, no. I ended up using seatgeek for the data I wanted which worked great. I did however get a response (3 months after I requested support) from their stubhub dev team. Nothing of use manifested from that

Answer (score 1):

setting custom headers on XHR requests triggers a preflight request.

I bet you're seeing an OPTIONS request without the `Authorization` header, and a corresponding response whose `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header value is not listing `Authorization`, or the API doesn't even allow unauthorized OPTIONS requests.

I don't know the stubhub api, but does it return CORS-compliant responses?

Comment: It does. When I use restangular, I can actually get a 200. I thought restangular was the problem so I switched over to just $http. THis is my other thread with restangular

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809680/200-response-but-no-json-data-returned-restangular-issue